# QGIS - how to display callouts only for labels offset more than a specified distance?

Tags: qgis, labeling, callout

I'd like to achieve the following:

1. Offset all labels for a point layer by a specified amount in general settings (I already know how to do this).
2. Only show callouts for the labels that I move manually a distance greater than that amount.

At present, when I offset all labels and switch on callouts, every label shows a callout. This is redundant in most cases as the offset is quite small. But there a few labels that I need to move further, due to them obscuring points on another layer, and I only want callouts to show up for these.

I'm relatively new to Qgis and despite searching this site and more widely, I haven't found a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the minimum length of the callout. Callouts shorter than this length will not be drawn.

[image]